# Icons are not appearing for angularjs-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use angular-dropdown-multiselect(copied from `https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect`) in my project but i wanted to try in fiddle first and then with my requirements after. here is the fiddler `https://plnkr.co/edit/N4kDga5boGJqghnPvtlu?p=preview`, icons are not appearing for some reason, is there something i am missing here?

Comment: Check your plnkr link, it points to "Hello World!" example.

Comment: @M.Czerwinski here is the link https://plnkr.co/edit/N4kDga5boGJqghnPvtlu?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons are not appearing because you included old version of bootstrap's css (2.3.2). As stated in [angulars-dropdown-multiselect dependencies](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect#dependencies), the requirements are:

> AngularJS >= 1.5, Bootstrap >= 3.0

Using bootstrap 3.3.7 fixed the issue:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
```

[see updated example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rWKt3poWHQpyBMNQ2iCw?p=preview)

You should also consider upgrading AngularJS version to 1.5 or newer, in your example you used unsupported version 1.4.12.